# Customizing the looks of GitAhead to resemble TortoiseHg workbench

Tags: gitahead

Is it possible to customize the looks of GitAhead to resemble TortoiseHg workbench?

I'm not asking for fonts or colors but for the position and display size of elements.

- branch selection + sort and filtering in one line full width at the top
- history log to be full width at the top under branch selection and filtering line
- commit details to be under with split screen (left for file list, right commit message and file changes)
- output log leave where it is (at the bottom)

If yes but only by modifying its source code on github https://github.com/gitahead/gitahead then I would appreciate some guidance

Comment: From all versioning system guis tortoisehg is really the best. Its not fancy, but highly productive. Plus it gives you 99,5% of all the special commands - you rarely need a shell! Also some equivalent to the beautiful patchqueue is missed with git(ahead). So yes, the more the git gui's learn from the best, the better. I only can support this request

Answer (score 1):

The design is hard coded. Any docks are used to change the look.
I tried to implement a mode to fullscreen the diffs or the commit list. Maybe you are interested in it
https://github.com/gitahead/gitahead/pull/408

At the moment the author is quite busy and is not able to have a look at all these changes.